# Dealing with whitespace and linebreaks in XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, whitespace, line-breaks

I need to find a way to deal with the whitespace and linebreaks in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<Message.body>
<Text>This is
    an attachment text
    with whitespaces and linebreaks
    File name: https://somerandomurl.com/123.txt
    File Type: txt
</Text>
</Message.body>
```

And here's the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(starts-with(Message.body/Text, 'This is an attachment link:'))" />
        <xsl:otherwise>
            xxx
        </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
   <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(Message.body/Text, 'File Name: '), 'File Type: ')"/>
   </Name>
   <Type>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Message.body/Text, 'File Type: ')"/>
   </Type>
</root>
```

This part:

```
<xsl:when test="(starts-with(Message.body/Text, 'This is an attachment link:'))" />
```

Does not work of course because of the linebreak with spaces in between. Also, the following lines do not with the desired result due to mentioned issues:

Actual result:

```
<Name>https://somerandomurl.com/123.txt
    </Name>
<Type>txt
  </Type>
```

Desired result:

```
<Name>https://somerandomurl.com/123.txt</Name>
<Type>txt</Type>
```

Should I try to replace all linebreaks with whitespaces, or is there an easier approach with XSLT 1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) to solve both issues...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with(normalize-space(Message.body/Text), 'This is an attachment link:')" />
      <xsl:otherwise>
        xxx
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <Name>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(Message.body/Text), 'File name: '), 'File Type: '))"/>
    </Name>
    <Type>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(Message.body/Text, 'File Type: '))"/>
    </Type>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the string comparison in substring-after and substring-before is case sensitive so I had to change `File Name:` to `File name:` to match your input.